# how to wait for all requests to complete before doing the next action (fetch)

Tags: javascript

I go through all the elements of the array and form a request for each, how can I display a success message only after all requests have been completed?

```
  saveAllPages() {
    const allStagesData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data.pages)).map(el => {
        const id = el.id
        apiService.postCurrentScript(el, id)

   
      ??? alert('success')
}
```

Maybe I should use Promise all, but how implement it here?

Comment: In short `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using async-await as it makes code cleaner. Async-await is just an alternaitive to using promises and is many times considered a better choice. I have converted your function into arrow function. The implementation is given below:

```js
saveAllPages = async () => {
    const allStagesData = await (function which returns promise);
    if(allStagesData){
        alert("success");
    }    
}

saveAllPages();
```

Comment: I wonder how is it working? await is working only on Promises (such as function which return Promise, or `Promise.all` etc.). `map` doesn't return Promise so `await` has no effect..

Comment: You're right @MoshFeu . I was focusing on the usage of async/await. So, i will edit the code!